# Installing missing firmware in debian

Tags: linux, debian, debian-installer, firmware

During installation I got a few pop ups stating that hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate.  At that time I didn't have those files so I continued with the installation, but now my now system is not able to recognize wifi. I tried installing firmware but whatever from searching from didn't at all work.

The missing files are:

- `rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin`
- `rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin`

Now I completed the installation, how can I install the firmware?

Answer (score 12):

You need to enable `non-free` first: edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and at the end of lines ending with `main`, add `contrib non-free`. You'll end up with something like

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

etc.

Then update your repositories and install `firmware-realtek`:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

That will provide the necessary firmware files.

Comment: Thank you. Many guides to this process say something like "add non-free to your sources" without saying what that means specifically.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a wired internet connection you can install `sudo apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree`

Alternative way in Debian 8 Jessie:

Download firmware.zip or tar.gz from [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/testing/current/) :

and extract all files of the zipped archive in folder `/lib/firmware` and then restart.
See also [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware) :

Provide Firmware during installation:
Just for the record when i want to be sure that all recent firmware will be available during a fresh Debian Jessie installation i follow these steps:

- I download the Debian 8 iso image i like (stable, testing, etc)
- I burn Debian iso image to a usb stick
- I download seperately the package [firmware.tar.gz](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/testing/current/)
- I copy firmware.tar.gz inside folder "firmware" of the installation cd.
- I extract firmware.tar.gz inside folder "firmware" of installation cd by using "extract here" option
- I accept any overwrite messages.
- Finally i boot with usb stick and firmware it is just there for sure.
- PS: I do the same procedure even if the Debian iso image claims that contains nonfree firmware, because in reality it has turned out that firmware maybe missing even from such iso images.

Comment: It says there is no such package...

Comment: If you run `apt list "firmware*"` do you get any results? Also make first `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @SarfrazRoboRex Check the alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

For Debian Buster, with internet access, a mix of the two other response is what you need to go :

> You need to enable non-free first: edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and at
>   the end of lines ending with `main`, add `contrib non-free`. You'll end up
>   with something like

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
```

Once that's saved, update the indexes with the new package lists:

```
sudo apt update
```

You can now install

```
sudo apt install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

and eventually:

```
sudo apt install firmware-realtek
```