# No wireless network option / network hardware is not working properly on Debian "bullseye" stable

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, debian-installer

I have a fresh install of Debian "bullseye" stable but I am unable to connect to the internet wirelessly. As you can see in my settings under "Network", "wireless" is not even an option.

[image]

During the installation process, I got some missing firmware issues during the "detect network hardware"[image]

I do not know why I do not have the necessary firmware. Nonetheless, I continued with the installation and then during the "configure the network" stage, I got the following screen:

[image]

The output of `uname -a` on my system is `Linux debian 5.10.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.178-3 (2023-04-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Some more backstory / relevant information:
I was first experiencing this issue of no network detection when I had Fedora installed on the computer. The wireless connection used to work on that machine until one day, I opened up and poof no option to connect to wireless. I decided that I would distro hop to debian in hopes that the wireless network issue would be resolved. But clearly I am having the same issue with debian.
Interestingly, however, is I first tried to install the i386 version of debian and in that installation, my wireless network did work. So I assume it is not a problem with the network hardware itself.

Can anyone help me diagnose what the issue is? Do I need to manually install the missing firmware that the debian installation was complaining about?

Comment: Yes, that would be the first step: manually install the firmware.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani apologies for my ignorance but where can I find all of those firmware files that I need?

Comment: I found this resource https://github.com/wkennington/linux-firmware ..is this what I am looking for?

Comment: You need to find out first which wireless card you have. Then you can search and download the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just as the debian installer mentioned, my computer was missing some firmware for my network hardware for one reason or another. So all I had to do was install the firmware.

What I did:

1. Figure out what network controller my computer has by running `lspci`

For me I had the following:

> Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)

2. Find the firmware on the internet and download it.

For my intel network controller, I was able to find it here. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

3. Transfer the .tgz to your machine and install it

First need to unzip it: `tar -xvzf /path/to/yourfile.tgz`
The folder I unzipped had a README file on how to then install the firmware. For me I had to run `cp iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode /lib/firmware`

Answer (score 0):

here is similar question that had already been asked [Installing missing firmware in debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336533/installing-missing-firmware-in-debian)

Try installing missing firmware from non-free debian repositories.

1. edit **/etc/apt/sources.list** and add **contrib non-free** at the end of each repository URL

> deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main **contrib non-free**

> deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main **contrib non-free**

> deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main **contrib non-free**

2. sudo apt update && sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi